# GeoServer WMS 16bit output

Tags: geoserver

Tiles are rendered using PostGIS as the store. Is it possible to output the tiles using a raster like style with 16bit values instead of 8bit values?

The goal is to provide more depth in the grayscale. The colouring is done on client side using WebGL. Because of the 8bit png output only 255 bins are available and this is limiting.

Comment: Could you use WCS instead?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: The goal would still be to visualise the data on the geographic map. Is this possible with WCS? I am now using Geoserver default 'raster' style with limits the color scale to 255 bins. This means in a raster with min/max values 0 till e.g. 1000, the spikes might be flattened out?

Comment: The geoserver documentation provides options for these two formats (and more): image/png and image/png8. This There seems to be no difference in the output.